# estoy tratando de encontrar una forma que el programa me diga cuando una palabra tiene 2 vocales seguidas

Tags: python

Por ejemplo en caso de Europa que mi respuesta sea 1 y en caso de python sea 0
esto es lo que llevo(que es nada), sin funciones ni importaciones

```
i = 0
while i < len(palabra1):
    if palabra1[i] == VOCALES:
        Contador = Contador + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

(Usando expresiones regulares)

El patrón "[aeiouAEIOU]" reconoce vocales. Si agregamos un "{2}" al patrón, reconocera exactamente dos vocales seguidas.

Podemos usar `findall` para aplicar el patrón a un texto y obtener una lista con todos los pares de vocales. Contando el número de elementos sabemos cuantos pares hay.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile("[aeiouAEIOU]{2}")

tests = ["Europa", "murcielago", "aaeeiioouu", "python"]

for test in tests:
    pares = patron.findall(test)
    print(test, pares, len(pares))
```

produce:

```
Europa ['Eu'] 1
murcielago ['ie'] 1
aaeeiioouu ['aa', 'ee', 'ii', 'oo', 'uu'] 5
python [] 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Y sabes de una forma sin funciones ni import

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer de esta manera

```py
resultados = [] #aqui se guardan los resultados
vocales = "aeiou" #indicamos las vocales
palabra1 = "Europa" #la palabra

ant = None
#recorremos cada letra de la palabra
for letra in palabra1:
    if ant and letra.lower() in vocales and ant in vocales:
        resultados.append(f"{letra}{ant}")
    ant = letra.lower()

print(resultados)
```

En la condición verificamos que la letra actual esté dentro de las vocales y que la letra anterior también esté en las vocales, si se cumple esa condición entonces agregamos las letras a la lista, luego actualizamos la variable `ant` para que sea la letra actual. Con `ant=None` decimos que al principio no habrá una letra anterior, por lo que al principio del ciclo no se cumplirá ya que no hay una letra anterior.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, sabes si se puede con While?

Comment: si se puede, lo quite por lo que veía innecesario

Comment: podrias mostrar como seria con while en vez de for in

Comment: solo cambia el `for` por `while` y cambia la variable `letra` por `palabra[i]` y no te olvides de sumar 1 a `i`. No es muy difícil

Comment: si, si eso si lo entiendo lo que no entiendo es que ocurre con el resultando.append y luego el ant = letra.lower

Comment: el método `append` sirve para añadir valores a una lista en este caso estamos añadiendo el valor `letra` y `ant`. La variable `ant` contiene la letra anterior a la que estamos. Con `ant = letra.lower()` estamos asignando la letra actual (en minuscula) a la variable `ant`

Comment: si entiendo la función en el ciclo for, pero ya que es un while, letra no estaría definida, por lo que no entiendo cual seria su funcion en el while o como reemplazarlo en el while

Comment: reemplázalo por `palabra1[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes contar cada diptongo así:

```py
palabra='bcaanefiaeefo'
vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

for vocal2 in vocales:
    print([palabra.count(vocal1+vocal2) for vocal1 in vocales])
```

Salida:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Si cuentas el número de diptongos en la matríz anterior y es mayor a 1, quiere decir que almenos hay un diptongo:

```py
palabra='bcaanefiaeefo'
vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

result=[]
for vocal2 in vocales:
    result.append(sum([palabra.count(vocal1+vocal2) for vocal1 in vocales]))

if sum(result)>0:
    print('Hay almenos un diptongo')
```